# Alias defined in .bashrc not working after pipe

Tags: bash, pipe, alias, bashrc

I'm stuck with the following problem.

I've defined an alias in `.bashrc` (and `.bash_profile`):

```
alias echo2="echo"
```

This works well:

```
$ echo2 "test"
test
```

However, if I try to use it after a redirect, it doesn't work:

```
ls | awk '{print "echo2 "$1}' | bash
bash: line 1: echo2: command not found
bash: line 2: echo2: command not found
...
```

Does someone know why? How I could make it work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're piping it into a new `bash` process as input. That process doesn't load your initialization scripts though, so there's no alias defined.

Check the section *INVOCATION* in `man bash`: Depending on the file in which you defined the alias, you need to make the `bash` process either a login shell (`-l`) or interactive (`-i`) to load that file.

There's an additional restriction: Aliases are ignored when the shell isn't interactive. There's a workaround though:

```
   Aliases  are not expanded when the shell is not interactive, unless the
   expand_aliases shell option is set using shopt (see the description  of
   shopt under SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS below).
```

Alternatively, you could look into using shell *functions* instead of aliases.